# How do i store into a MongoDB database and read/load from the same MongoDB database using Java?

Tags: java, database, mongodb

How do i store into a MongoDB database and read from the MongoDB database using Java?...

I've written this code where the database is created and the details are stored but i cant seem to read the files properly. It works but the data is not being loaded.

```
private void saveandloadData(String[] trainSeats, String[] customerName, String[] traincustomerSeats, String userInput) {
        MongoClient dbb = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
        DB dbs = dbb.getDB("TrainCustomerandSeats");

        DBCollection coll1 = dbs.getCollection("CW1");
        DBCollection coll2 = dbs.getCollection("CW2");
        DBCollection coll3 = dbs.getCollection("CW3");

        if (userInput == "S" || userInput == "s"){
            storeData(trainSeats, customerName, traincustomerSeats, coll1, coll2, coll3);
        }else{
            loadData(trainSeats, customerName, traincustomerSeats, coll1, coll2, coll3);
        }
        optionEnter(trainSeats, customerName, traincustomerSeats);
    }
```

here is the part where i store the data into the db:

```
private void storeData(String[] trainSeats, String[] customerName, String[] traincustomerSeats, DBCollection coll1, DBCollection coll2, DBCollection coll3) {

        BasicDBObject oneDoc = new BasicDBObject();
        for (int k = 1; k < trainSeats.length; k++){
            oneDoc.append(String.valueOf(k), trainSeats[k]);
        }
        coll1.insert(oneDoc);

        BasicDBObject twoDoc = new BasicDBObject();
        for(int k = 1; k < customerName.length; k++){
            twoDoc.append(String.valueOf(k), customerName[k]);
        }
        coll2.insert(twoDoc);

        BasicDBObject threeDoc = new BasicDBObject();
        for(int k = 1; k < traincustomerSeats.length; k++){
            threeDoc.append(String.valueOf(k), traincustomerSeats[k]);
        }
        coll3.insert(threeDoc);
    }
```

and here is where i load the details from the db but it doesn't seem to work for some reason:

```
private void loadData(String[] trainSeats, String[] customerName, String[] traincustomerSeats, DBCollection coll1, DBCollection coll2, DBCollection coll3) {

        Cursor cursor  = coll1.find();
        Cursor cursor2 = coll2.find();
        Cursor cursor3 = coll3.find();

        while(cursor.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }
        while(cursor2.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(cursor2.next());
        }
        while(cursor3.hasNext()){
            System.out.println(cursor3.next());
        }
    }
```

here is the output when this is run - [click to open output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fjjh.png)

Comment: Look into how MongoDB handles **transactions**.  My guess is that all your updates are getting thrown away because they happened in an implicit transaction that was never committed.  Because you started a _new connection_ before doing the load.  the old connection on which you did the updates got closed, so the uncommitted transaction in progress (containing all your updates) was rolled back.

Comment: @KevinAnderson yea thats wht i thought as well but then how do we make it so that a new connection is not begun and rather go ahead with the previous old connection ?

Comment: Don't make the connection in `saveandloadData`; open a connection at the highest level of your program and then pass it as an argument to `saveandloadData` and any other methods that need DB access.  But if you don't commit your transactions, your updates will never go _permanently_ to the database; they'll live only as long your program---and its one connection to the database---live.